# Handling taxonomy fields in drupal7

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy, drupal-7

The taxonomy system changed a lot since Drupal 6. What is the best way to get all taxonomy term IDs associated with a single node in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$terms = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_tags', array('default'));
```

Comment: I've read that book too:) But is this the best practice? I mean that function will retrieve a big multi-level array (with an object in it) and I have to search for the term ids manually. It's just a little bit better then to search the whole node object manually.

Comment: You could fetch the tids from DB using `SELECT field_tags_tid FROM field_data_field_tags WHERE entity_type = 'node' AND entity_id = $nid` as a starter.

Comment: So you mean there is no functions for this in the drupal-7 api? A function wich gets the term ids from a given (term-reference)field would be enough... It's strange for me if there is no such thing in drupal7.

Comment: Try `field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tags')`.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to get these terms ? In a module, a theme ...?

Did you take a look at :
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module

Comment: In a module. I need a function something like taxonomy_node_get_terms() was in drupal-6. I've already checked the API doc. It's possible that I was careless, but I didn't find anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

The field_data_field_tags table just covers the default Tags field, that might or might not exist and you might have other taxonomies too.

However, taxonomy.module still maintains the taxonomy_term_data/taxonomy_index tables which you can query:

```
SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE nid = :nid
```

Or if you want a specific vocabulary ID:

```
SELECT ti.tid FROM {taxonomy_index} ti INNER JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} ttd ON ttd.tid = ti.tid WHERE ti.nid = :nid AND vid = :vid
```

Completely untested.